# Defining Items Based on Text File (C#)

Tags: c#, file, text, macros

I'm setting up a list of items that looks something like this.

```
List<BankInfo> all_branches = new List<BankInfo>();
Equipment.set_slot = "Mail";
all_branches.Add(new BankInfo
{
    name = "West Bank",
    city = "San Francisco",
    owner = new Person { name = "Jeff Bridges", age = 55 }
});
all_branches.Add(new BankInfo
{
    name = "East Bank",
    city = "Concord",
    owner = new Person { name = "Upton Sinclair", age = 102 }
});
```

Writing literally hundreds of these is quite cumbersome and I'd much prefer if I got to write it like this

```
--
Name: West Bank
City: San Francisco
Owner: Jeff Bridges, 55
--
Name: East Bank
City: Concord
Owner: Upton Sinclair, 102
```

Is there any way to do such a thing?

At the very least is there any way (in c#) to make it so that a symbol like $ITEM becomes all_branches.Add(new BankInfo { so I could just do $ITEM (like macros in C++)?

Comment: How about reading all this data from an Text or XML file and then writing a function to do all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that what you mean is a function taking care of all the property assignation:

```
private List<BankInfo> addToBankInfo(string name, string city, string owner_name, int owner_age, List<BankInfo> all_branches)
{
     return all_branches.Add(new BankInfo { name = name, city = city, owner = new Person { name = owner_name, age = owner_age } });
}
```

Which you can call:

```
List<BankInfo> all_branches = new List<BankInfo>();
Equipment.set_slot = "Mail";
try
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("input_file.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line != null && line.Trim().Length > 0 && line.Contains(","))
            {
                string[] temp = line.Split(',');
                if(temp.Length >= 4)
                {
                    all_branches = addToBankInfo(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], Convert.ToInt32(temp[3]), all_branches);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

In the example above I am assuming that all the inputs are in a TXT file, separated by commas. If you provide more information about the exact input format, I can update the code accordingly.

Comment: Ah! Silly me I forgot that of course you can simply read the information in from a text file. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: No problem. This is what this site is for :)